# After uploading sql file, how can I run that file?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am building a small website that displays sports data.  I get the new data via SQL file.  I am able to upload an .SQL file to my server, but get lost after that.

After upload I want to be able to run that same SQL file on the server, using it to populate/create MYSQL tables online.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: did u save the file as blob in ur bd? thats not good practise. you should rather save the link to the file and call that link.

Comment: the file isn't in my DB, it is just uploaded to the server as a file.  how do i call the link?

Comment: see the comment posted by @deep